# how to create menu with menubar in grails

Tags: grails, menu, grails-2.0, menubar

I need to create menu bar and menu in grails. I have no idea how to do it. Is there any easy way to complete it. Any link please. I am using grails 2.1.0. Is there any option to make menu using grails or I have to use html menu.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to add the line:

```
compile ':platform-core:1.0.RC5'
```

to plugins{ } under grails.project.dependency.resolution in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy

Then, edit grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp

Add this before the layoutBody tag:

```
<div class="nav" role="navigation">
    <nav:primary/>
    <nav:secondary/>
</div>
```

This should get you started. More info: http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Platform Core API plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/platform-core)

[Documentation here](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html)

I've not used it myself though

Comment: I have seen your link. But looks so complex. Cause I am new in grails. I think I should use jquery for generating menubar and menus and with grails may be later. Is there any jquery link for generating menu easily?